# gulp browser-sync не перезагружает страницу

Tags: gulp, gulp4

```
const 
gulp         = require('gulp'),
sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create(),
pug          = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "../view"
    },
    port: 8888
});

gulp.watch(['./scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.series("scss"));
gulp.watch('./pug/**/*.pug', gulp.series("pug"));
});

/* scss */
gulp.task("scss", function(){
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../view/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

/* pug */
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('./pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("../view"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

В консоль выводит надпись о перезагрузке. Но сама страница не перезагружается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить к обработке своих шаблонов перезагрузку страницы и вместо `browserSync.stream()` использовать `browserSync.reload()`.

```
/* pug */
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp
        .src('./pug/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../view"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload());
});
```

JS и CSS без перезагрузки обновляются, а HTML надо перезагружать. Хотя рекомендуют JS тоже подгружать с перезагрузкой.